# Get route values in ajax action + Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, routes

In `Post` Controller , URL is like this :

```
     http://127.0.0.1/post/5006/some-text-for-seo-friendly
     {contoller}/{id}/{seo}

     public ViewResult Index(){
     .....
     }
```

I used `Ajax.BeginForm` in index view and mapped it to `AddComment` action in the same controller.

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", "Post", new AjaxOptions()
                   {
                      HttpMethod = "GET",
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                      UpdateTargetId = "comment-container"
           }))
            {
                <textarea cols="2" rows="2" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
            }
```

and in controller

```
    public PartialViewResult AddComment(string comment){
              // how can I get 5006 {id} here
    }
```

my question is how can I get the `{id} [5006]` in `AddComment` action.

note : the hard way is using `Request.UrlReferrer` and split by `'/'` and select form array .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the `id` to the `BeginForm` method using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470605%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) which takes a `routeValues` parameter:

```
@using ( Ajax.BeginForm( "AddComment", "Post",
  new { id = 5006 },
  new AjaxOptions
  {
    ...
```

Then you should just be able to take the id as a parameter of your action method:

```
public PartialViewResult AddComment( int id, string comment )
{
  ...
```

MVC will call `AddComment` with the populated id value.

Comment: as far as I know the parameters of `Ajax Action` are mapped with the html tag's name which used in `Ajax.BeginForm` . Do you mean should I use some hidden field in Ajax Form and set value to `5002`?

Comment: Nicholas Butler , would you please check the question again .